# После обновления npm не устанавливаются пакеты

Tags: node.js, npm

Недавно npm мне сказал, что доступно обновление 6.7.0, для его установки надо ввести команду `npm install -g npm` После этого обновления не может скачаться ни один пакет.

```
# npm i festival
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/Programs/node-10.15.0-proposal/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/Programs/node-10.15.0-proposal/package.json'
npm WARN node-10.15.0-proposal No description
npm WARN node-10.15.0-proposal No repository field.
npm WARN node-10.15.0-proposal No README data
npm WARN node-10.15.0-proposal No license field.

+ festival@1.0.1
updated 1 package and audited 1934 packages in 3.252s
found 28 moderate severity vulnerabilities
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Версия Nodejs 10.15.0

Прошу помогите, как исправить?

Comment: `npm init` делали?

Comment: К слову, я не вижу фатальных проблем в логе, тут только ворнинги.

Comment: @Suvitruf То-есть тут никаких проблем нет? Просто я что-то увидел это и не проверил, установилась ли библиотека, вроде проверил и все работает. Но чтобы не пропадать вопросу зря, то как можно это исправить? Но все ровно спасибо!

Comment: Ну, ворнинги не фатальны, но по-хорошему их лучше исправить. Первые ворнингу у вас из-за того, что в `package.json` не все поля добавили. Они не обязательны, но желательны.

Comment: @Suvitruf А где лежит package.json, судя по логу, точно не в том каталоге

Comment: В корне проекта должен лежать.